# How to add image to label in ASP.net (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, label

I want to show up arrow and down arrow in aspx web page's label according to an condition like this

```
If successrate > x Then
        result = "upArrow"
    ElseIf successrate < x Then
        result = "Down"
    Else : result = "sameArrow"
    End If
```

and i got a idea do implement in windows Form using this method but dont know how to implement this in webpage please let me know is there any way to show up and down arrow or help me to change this codes in web page

```
Private Sub upArrow()
    img = Image.FromFile("C:\upArrow.jpg")
    Label1.Image = img
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Html "img" element to ASP.net Label's Text property as shown below. It works.

```
    string imagePath = "http://localhost:51746/WebSite1/Tulips.jpg";
    Label1.Text = string.Format("<img src='{0}' style='height:100px;width:100px;'/>", imagePath);
```

Comment: code is running but image is not appearing 
please help me

Comment: Try setting height and width as shown in the latest code snippet. Make sure Label.Text property is not set anywhere after setting the img element. if it still does not work, first directly add this img element in your webpage and test if image is loading. Problem might be with image path. I have tested this code locally. So, It should work.

Answer (score 0):

accordin to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9s25tee%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) you have to set the size of the label to the size of the image innorder to display it properly.

```
Private Sub upArrow()
img = Image.FromFile("C:\upArrow.jpg")
Label1.Size = img.Size     
Label1.Image = img
End Sub
```